# How to do simplest "If" statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, logic

Is there a way I can do this in simplest way? Let say I have 20 unique digits to be checked, its getting very long and messy. Any suggestions?

```
if (i==80 || i==86 || i==101, etc...){some codes}
```

Comment: Consider *indexOf* : `if ([80,86,101].indexOf(i) != -1) /* i is in array*/`.

Comment: Is this a JavaScript question or a Java question?  They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `in` ?

```
checklist = [1, 2, 3, 4];

if (i in checklist) {
    console.log("Found !");
}
```

Or

```
if (checklist.indexOf(i) !== -1) {
    console.log("Found !");
}
```

Comment: The *in* operator in a relational expressoin tests object property names, not values. `4 in [1,2,3,4]` returns false as there is no `4` property.

Answer (score 0):

Use a List with valid values.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> validNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
        {
            add(80);
            add(86);
            add(101);
            // ...
        }
    };

    int i = 0;
    System.out.println("Valid? " + validNumbers.contains(i));
    if (validNumbers.contains(i)) {
        // Do Something...
    }
    int j = 101;
    System.out.println("Valid? " + validNumbers.contains(j));
    if (validNumbers.contains(j)) {
        // Do Something...
    }

}
```

### Console

```
Valid?false
Valid?true
```

Comment: Double-brace initialization is unnecessarily complex.  What’s wrong with just `validNumbers = Arrays.asList(80, 86, 101)`?

Comment: It is true. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array with your values:

```
if ([80, 86, 101].indexOf(i) !== -1) { }
```

Or you can also use a switch:

```
switch(i) {
  case 80: 
  case 86:
    // do something...
  break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In ECMAScript 2017 there will be *includes*, so you can do:

```
var testValues = [80,86,101]; // values to test
if (testValues.includes(i)) {
  // i is in testValues
}
```